# Two infinite series converge, prove product converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2$$
are both convergent.
Prove that the following infinite series is convergent:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kb_k$$

$\\$

I am not fully sure how to go about this. This is all the info given in the problem and I think I'm just missing some sort of fundamental concept. Could anyone please explain the general idea behind this? I'd appreciate if you didn't just explicitly give me the answer, but maybe just a foundational piece to get me going as I really want to get this one by myself!

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy Schwarz inequality? This follows from that

Comment: We haven't used that in this chapter yet. Could I also try using the AM-GM inequality?? I think I just tried that and it worked out if at the end I apply the comparison test!

Comment: I do not know whether the AM-GM is sufficient for solving this question. I won't say don't give it a try, but I'm skeptical about it.

Comment: Yes, geometric-quadratic mean works also, resp. the summation of $0\le(b-a)^2\implies ab\le\frac12(a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: @LutzL It would be better to write this $|ab|\leq \dfrac12(a^2+b^2)$, in the present case, but it's a good hint!

Comment: I used the wrong name. The one mentioned by LutzL and Jean-Claude above is what I used! I figured it out. Thanks for the verification and help. I appreciate everyone's replies.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is via the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality